# java thread - why stopping a new thread is allowed

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question for the below statements

> When a thread is a new thread, it is merely an empty Thread object. No
>   system resources have been allocated for it yet. When a thread is in
>   this state, you can only start the thread or stop it. Calling any
>   method besides start or stop when a thread is in this state makes no
>   sense and causes an `IllegalThreadStateException`.

Why does java allow to stop a thread which is not even started... in which scenario one will have to invoke stop() and a new thread?

Comment: I doubt there's a specific scenario where that needs to happen. They probably considered that it doesn't matter, so it doesn't need to throw the exception. So you're free to call stop() on threads without making sure they have been started first.

Comment: stop() is deprecated anyway and should never be called, as the documentation indicates.

Comment: I would put it the other way: why should you forbid to stop a thread that is not running?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do no use the function which have been marked as `deprecated`.

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) indicates for Stop,

> It is permitted to stop a thread that has not yet been started. If the thread is eventually started, it immediately terminates.

Moreover, if I look at the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.stop%28%29) for `Stop` which is

```
 @Deprecated
 public final void stop() {
     // If the thread is already dead, return.
     // A zero status value corresponds to "NEW".
     if ((threadStatus != 0) && !isAlive()) {
         return;
     }
     stop1(new ThreadDeath());
 }
```

As you can see from code it is designed such that, it returns normally when  `threadStatus != 0` (A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW") or if the thread is already stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers address the specifics, so I'll try talking about the more general idea behind it.

Essentially, if designers don't allow methods being called, they are trying to detect programming errors. In the designers view, `interrupt()` being called when the thread was never started seemed likely to be a bug, whereas the same for `stop()` seemed less so.

There are other similar examples, too. For example, `Future#cancel()` can be called multiple times.

Ultimately I think there is an element of subjectivity/preference, even though in some cases one makes clearly more sense than the other.